# Какой механизм распознавания лучше использовать на ограниченной выборке очень маленьких изображений?

Tags: c#, .net, нейронные-сети, распознавание-символов

Товарищи!

Появилась необходимость в определении числа на картинке, причем размеры изображения оставляют желать лучшего *(21x26)*. Вот пример в натуральную величину:

[image: 20]

Решил использовать для этой цели `Tesseract OCR` (через net-wrapper `Tesseract`) таким образом:

```
private static TesseractEngine NumEngine
{
    get
    {
        if (_numEngine == null)
        {
            _numEngine = new TesseractEngine("tessdata", "eng");
            _numEngine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
            _numEngine.DefaultPageSegMode = PageSegMode.SingleLine;
        }
        return _numEngine;
    }
}
private static TesseractEngine _numEngine;

public static int RecognizeNum(Image Img)
{
    using (Page page = NumEngine.Process((Bitmap)ClearImage(Img)))
        if (int.TryParse(page.GetText(), out int result))
            return result;
    return -1;
}
```

Метод `ClearImage` проводит бинаризацию изображения, превращая его в нечто подобное:

[image: 20-binarized]

Алгоритм метода `ClearImage` (код не привожу, ибо там обильно используются мои библиотеки):

1. Определяем цвет числа (он может быть разным), находя в изображении
   самый яркий цвет
2. Все похожие на него цвета заменяем черным, а остальные - белым
3. Возвращаем значимую (содержащую данные) зону изображения

`Tesseract` в принципе показывает весьма хорошие результаты, но иногда ошибается, принимая, скажем, `8` за `3`, `3` за `8`, `6` за `15` и так далее

Однако очень важно, чтобы ошибок не было **вовсе**! Тут важно упомянуть, что выборка весьма и весьма ограничена: возможны лишь числа от `0` до `37` включительно. Так что, возможно, стоит накинуть свою нейронную сеть, решая типичную задачу классификации для 38 возможных элементов

---

Итого, вопрос таков:

Что лучше использовать: `Tesseract OCR`, если есть какая-то возможность улучшить его результаты (вот только как?), или же все таки свою нейронную сеть, заточенную под конкретную задачу (и какие бы параметры стоило бы к ней подобрать)?

Comment: Я бы сделал тупо сетку (зону), позицировл бы её по-максимум на изображение, и превратил бы изображение в массив, где примерно 10 значений - уровень черного белого в зонах. Потом прошелся бы по массиву "заготовок", составил бы средне (квадратическое или обычное) отклонение по полям. Минимальное отклонение - даст желаемый результат. И распознавал бы каждую цифру отдельно.

Comment: Думаю... можно провести прямую... или виляющую +/-1 линию, и разделить числа. Судя по вашему скрину - у вас одно число налезает на другое. Раздельное распознавание даст результат лучше.

Comment: @nick_n_a: хорошие варианты! Надо проверить

Comment: Если вы планируете использовать нейронные сети, то `чтобы ошибок не было вовсе` и `выборка весьма и весьма ограничена` - взаимоисключающие вещи. Да и не бывает сетей дающих 100%-ю правильность. Попробуйте скормить картинки __после__ обработки Tesseract'у. В последних версиях Tesseract используются очень хорошо обученные НС с использованием LSTM.

Comment: @MaxU: немного не то хотел сказать: выборка ограничен в том плане, что там всего 38 возможных значений. А картинок я могу набрать хоть 100000 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Я на данный момент использую Tesseract 3.5, в 4.0, думаете, ситуация получше? Я думал, там основные изменения связаны лишь с тем, что убрали Cube-engine для пары языков в духе хинди

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, главное изменение в версии 4.0 - это использвание НС с LSTM алгоритмом - попробуйте его использовать на очищенных картинках... Расскажете потом как получилось?

Comment: @MaxU: о. А я грешным делом думал, что LSTM там ещё до 4.0 вовсю применяется... Спасибо, протестирую!